# Hadoop map/reduce shows Error: com.mongodb.connection.SslSettings$Builder.context(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;)

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce

I run map/reduce jobs regularly, and lately I have been getting this kind of log :

> 17/09/27 10:38:03 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 27% reduce 0%
>   17/09/27 10:38:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id :
>    attempt_1494368272823_5583_m_000014_0, Status : FAILED
>   Error: com.mongodb.connection.SslSettings$Builder.context(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;)Lcom/mongodb/connection/SslSettings$Builder;
>   17/09/27 10:38:08 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 30% reduce 0%
>   17/09/27 10:38:10 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 30% reduce 6%
>   17/09/27 10:38:43 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 32% reduce 6%
>   17/09/27 10:38:45 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 33% reduce 6%
>   17/09/27 10:38:46 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 33% reduce 7%
>   17/09/27 10:38:49 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 35% reduce 7%
>   17/09/27 10:38:52 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 35% reduce 8%
>
> 17/09/27 10:39:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1494368272823_5583_m_000008_0, Status : FAILED
>   Error: com.mongodb.connection.SslSettings$Builder.context(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;)Lcom/mongodb/connection/SslSettings$Builder;
>   Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
>   Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
>   Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
>
> 17/09/27 10:39:16 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 40% reduce 10%

And ends with:

> 17/09/27 10:44:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1494368272823_5583 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1494368272823_5583_m_000025
>   Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0
>
> 17/09/27 10:44:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 41
>           File System Counters
>                   FILE: Number of bytes read=0
>                   FILE: Number of bytes written=5481350
>                   FILE: Number of read operations=0
>                   FILE: Number of large read operations=0
>                   FILE: Number of write operations=0
>                   HDFS: Number of bytes read=3430808431
>                   HDFS: Number of bytes written=2495944
>                   HDFS: Number of read operations=5540
>                   HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
>                   HDFS: Number of write operations=118
>           Job Counters
>                   Failed map tasks=21
>                   Killed map tasks=9
>                   Killed reduce tasks=1
>                   Launched map tasks=47
>                   Launched reduce tasks=1
>                   Other local map tasks=20
>                   Data-local map tasks=26
>                   Rack-local map tasks=1
>                   Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=34635900
>                   Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=3707820
>                   Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=3463590
>                   Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=370782
>                   Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=3463590
>                   Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=370782
>                   Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=34635900000
>                   Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=3707820000
>           Map-Reduce Framework
>                   Map input records=18
>                   Map output records=9722
>                   Map output bytes=2572358
>                   Map output materialized bytes=2608684
>                   Input split bytes=3387
>                   Combine input records=0
>                   Spilled Records=9722
>                   Failed Shuffles=0
>                   Merged Map outputs=0
>                   GC time elapsed (ms)=62408
>                   CPU time spent (ms)=1809020
>                   Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=56575217664
>                   Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=155695132672
>                   Total committed heap usage (bytes)=60439920640
>           File Input Format Counters
>                   Bytes Read=0
>   MapReduce failed with 1

Sometimes the job actually finishes successfully. Sometimes it's as the above. There is no more information given in the logs. I will appreciate any insight as to what exactly is happening that causes this failure? It doesn't seem to be a timeout or memory issues as far as I could tell. The cluster is not overloaded (I checked)...

Edit: after further debugging it seems like the issue happens in the "connect" method when I am connecting to MongoDB. But why would this happen? Connection is successful when I try manual and it works some of the times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you use a `MongoClient` instance.

In that case, please verify if the parameters related to `SSLContext` is set as mentioned in this below reference:
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/driver/tutorials/ssl/

"Java Secure Socket Extension (JSSE) Reference Guide" will be a good read to know more about `SSLContext`:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html

And you will find ample number of examples on creating an instance of `SSLContext`.

Else, most probably you are running into this issue:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2590

**Excerpt from that link**:

> an older version of mongodb-driver-core is being pulled in

Please clean-up your dependency and use the latest one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Why do you believe that this will solve the problem? Why is setting SSL as "true" will resolve it? Also if the wrong mongodb driver was pulled I guess it would fail 100% of the time no? It fails some of the times and sometimes it passes so it seems like a different issue...

Comment: @Idos, those are the directions I would investigate based on that error from the log file, to make sure everything is ok. I believe that there could be more than 
 one version of dependency jar in the execution environment. Did you check that by any chance?

Comment: Brilliant. I had 2 different mongo drivers one was under 3.5 in another module dependency  so did not have the newer class. Changing both to 3.5 solved the problem! Thanks!

Comment: @Idos Good to know. Welcome!